# com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.SSLSMWA class of caffeine-cache consuming very high memory

Tags: java, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, caffeine-cache

I have initialized my cache in the following way:

```
Cache<Key, Entry> sharedCache =Caffeine.newBuilder()
                 .ticker (ticker::read)
                 .expireAfter(new ExpirySetting())
                 .weigher( a weigher logic that calculates the bytes consumed by each entry value)
                 .maximumWeight(maxBytesInMemory) //maxBytesInMemory =242 MB
                 .executor(executor)
                 .scheduler(scheduler)
                 .build();
```

There is a **weightedSize** variable that keeps track of the total weight consumed at any point of time. When the value of this reaches the **maxWeightedSize** (242 MB as set in the caffeine initialization), eviction start to happen as expected.

but the object com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.SSLSMWA consumes a lot of memory (way higher than the maxWeightedSize i.e 242 MB), example of such instances are provided below:

*Unique requests were sent at the rate of 25 per second for 40 mins so that all the requests are getting writen to cache and heap dumps were taken every 3 min. Below are the observations:*

```
com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.SSLSMWA: 262.4 MB | maxWeightedSize: 242.194645 MB | weightedSize: 198.201916 MB | time elapsed: 18 min
{Retained size of SSLSMWA (262.4 MB) already exceeded the max weight (242 MB) but the weighted size is still below max weight.}

com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.SSLSMWA:289.2 MB | maxWeightedSize: 242.194645 MB | weightedSize: 218.480108 MB | time elapsed: 21 min

com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.SSLSMWA:314.3 MB] maxWeightedSize: 242.194645 MB | weightedSize: 237.563964 MB | time elapsed: 24 min

com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.SSLSMWA:320.5 MB | maxWeightedSize: MB | weightedSize: 242.193292 MB | time elapsed : 27 min
{weighted size approaches maxweight}

com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.SSLSMWA: 299.1 MB | maxWeightedSize: 242.194645 MB | weightedSize: 226.00419 MB | time elapsed: 30 min {weighted size starts to reduce, retained size of SSLSMWA also starts to reduce}

com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.SSLSMWA: 258.8 MB | maxWeightedSize: 242.194645 MB | weightedSize: 195.53424 MB | time elapsed: 33 min

com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.SSLSMWA: 231.9 MB | maxWeightedSize: 242.194645 MB | weightedSize: 175.148864 MB | time elapsed: 36 min
```

Can you please answer the following questions ?

1.) What is the use of SSLSMWA class?

2.) Why is the com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.SSLSMWA consuming so much memory (causing my application to use 99% of the heap)? Why is it not contained within the maxWeightedSize (i.e. 242 MB)

Comment: fyi, this is also being discussed on the [github issue](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/issues/1356).